# Securing Facebook

Tags: privacy, redirect

Probably like most of you, I am concerned about the privacy of Facebook. Some people suggested that I use the HTTPS address instead. Unfortunately, many links in the HTTPS page itself link back to HTTP. So I am wondering whether it is possible in Ubuntu to redirect any request to:

http://www.facebook.com/

to

https://www.facebook.com/

This way I feel safer.

If you also know the solution for Windows, it might be great to share (probably as a comment to my question rather than answer, as this forum is supposed to be for Ubuntu) so that I can share it with friends.

Comment: This is not a [discussion] forum, but a collection of questions and answers (Q&A).

Comment: off topic, you are seeking to manipulate the web content from a browser, in a way that might not be supported by the web server/application. Also please be aware that privacy concerns are related to how the information posted on facebook is handled, changing from http to https only affects how it's transported over the network.

Comment: you should join Diaspora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted, Facebook supports this already.

Go to [account settings](https://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php) and scroll down to account security:

[image]

Comment: Like I said, its not out for everyone yet. Lucky you! :P

Comment: It should be out by now. For a while, it was in the process of being rolled out and only some people had it.

Answer (score 3):

as far as i concern it should be handled by browsers not the OS. There are already some plugins/extensions for almost all browser to force the sites to use https:

Firefox --- NoScript
Chrome  --- Use HTTPS

There is also a user script for internet explorer.

Just read this tutorial for detailed info: http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/31/how-to-force-https-connections/

Hope This helps

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

For firefox [this](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) addon also ensures https connection for many popular sites including facebook

Answer (score 1):

Facebook now has an option in your setting that will force https.  Everything works except you have to leave https to use some applications

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is releasing HTTPS version for their site slowly to all users. You will find the option soon in your settings. I read the article sometime back. Hope that helps.

Comment: Its available for every one now